# CORS work correctly on sharing host but not in localhost

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, cors

I try to build a simple api base app with Laravel (as backend) and angularjs (as frontend). 
In the beginning, I faced this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/myroute. Response
>   to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

- `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/myroute` is my route to get some data, defined in Laravel as POST route.

That's while I've added the CORS middleware on my routes (according [this sample](http://en.vedovelli.com.br/2015/web-development/Laravel-5-1-enable-CORS/)) in this way:
**Cors Middleware:**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token');
    }
```

and the below code is my `$http` code that I send request in Angularjs:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/myroute',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
}).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
}, function (reject) {
    console.log(reject);
});
```

I should to add this point that when I upload my project on a host, this Cors works Ok!
My problem is just `http://localhost`.

I also tried this in **Firefox** but the result was same, just Firefox not shown the Cross Origin Error and it's the only difference.

In this time I could not develop my project on host and I need to work locally. 
So I need help!

Comment: Weird that you are seeing a url with the loopback ip but the original is local host. Have you tried ` url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/myroute',`?

Comment: Another work around I use when developing locally (I'm on windows) is to add a FQDN to my host file. The line will look like this `dev.somesite.local 127.0.0.1` and then I can use   `url: 'http://dev.somesite.local/api/myroute'

Comment: thanks for your comments, About first, Yes! I tried both, there is no difference between them. About second comment, I did it too but its same as localhost or 127.0.0.1

Comment: can you load http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/myroute. in a web browser? What happens when you use PostMan or CURL without AJAX. Can you verify the cors headers are in the response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add below codes as header to your laravel's index.php file:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Authorization');
```

**but be careful about cross origion!**